# Make css class invalid on specified screen width

Tags: html, css

I have modal that displays images. I set height of image in modal on 90% and width automaticly scales with it, so image is not stretched. But on the mobile phone I want the `height` to not be defined and I want to define only width to 100%. How do I make height of the image on small screen not defined? till now I have this code:

```
.image {
  height: 80%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .image {
     width: 100%;
     /* make height not defined?!
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `height: auto;` in mobile screens.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
   }
}
```

Comment: it is still the same result, seems to not make the first height definition invalid..

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
   }
}
```